# Correct use of cursors for very large result sets in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-cursor

**Short version of my question:**

If I hold a cursor reference to an astronomically huge result set in my client code, would it be ridiculous (i.e. completely defeats the point of cursors) to issue "FETCH ALL FROM cursorname" as my next command? Or would this slowly stream the data back to me as I consume it (at least in principle, assuming that I have a well written driver sitting between me and Postgres)?

**More detail**

If I understand things at all correctly, then Postgres cursors are REALLY for dealing with the following problem [even though they can be used (abused?) for other things, such as returning multiple different result sets from one function]:

> Note: The current implementation of RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY
>   stores the entire result set before returning from the function, as
>   discussed above. That means that if a PL/pgSQL function produces a
>   very large result set, performance might be poor: data will be written
>   to disk to avoid memory exhaustion, but the function itself will not
>   return until the entire result set has been generated.

(ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

But (again if I understand correctly) when you write a function which returns a cursor then the whole query is NOT buffered into memory (and disk) before the user of the function can start to consume anything, but instead the results can be consumed bit by bit. (There is more overhead setting up and using the cursor, but it's worth it to avoid massive buffer allocation for very large result sets.)

(ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN66551)

I would like to understand how this relates to SELECTS and FETCHES over the wire to a Postgres server.

In all cases, I'm talking about consuming results from client code which is communicating with Postgres on a socket behind the scenes (using the Npgsql library in my case, actually).

Q1: What if I try to execute "SELECT * FROM AstronomicallyLargeTable" as my only command over the wire to Postgres? Will that allocate all the memory for the entire select and then start to send data back to me? Or will it (effectively) generate its own cursor and stream the data back a little at a time (with no huge additional buffer allocation on the server)?

Q2: What if I already have a cursor reference to an astronomically large result set (say because I've already done one round trip, and got back the cursor reference from some function), and then I execute "FETCH ALL FROM cursorname" over the wire to Postgres? Is that stupid, because it will allocate ALL the memory for all the results *on the Postgres server* before sending anything back to me? Or will "FETCH ALL FROM cursorname" actually work as I'd like it to, streaming the data back slowly as I consume it, without any massive buffer allocation happening on the Postgres server?

**EDIT: Further clarification**

I'm asking about a case where I know that my data access layer streams the data from the server to me one row at a time  (so *no* large client-side buffers involved there, however long the data streams for) and where I also know that my own application consumes the data one row at a time and then discards it (so *no* client-side buffers there, either). I definitely DON'T want to fetch all these rows into client side memory, and then do something with them. I see that that would be completely daft!

So I think all the issues (for the just-described use case) are about how long PostgreSQL would take to start streaming and how much of a memory buffer it would allocate, for a `FETCH ALL`. IF (and it's a big 'IF'...) PostgreSQL *doesn't* allocate a huge buffer of all rows before starting, and if it streams the rows back to Npgsql one at a time, starting quickly, then I believe (but please tell me why/if I'm wrong) that there still IS a clear use case for `FETCH ALL FROM cursorname`!

Comment: PostgreSQL allocates memory for result on client side. For big result you needs lot of memory on client side. `FETCH ALL` is very similar to classic `SELECT`. More typical usafe (you don't need too much memory, you don't need to wait too long) is `FETCH NEXT 10000` in cycle.

Comment: @pavel-stehule Thank you! But the info I need to find out about is what happens on the server side. In fact (I think you'll agree?) PostgreSQL doesn't do anything at all on the client side! Npgsql and then my application do. Npgsql streams the data. If my application uses the data one row at a time, then I think no large buffers are ever needed on the client, however large the result set is.

Comment: Npgsql always works in "single-row" mode - it never buffers the entire resultset. It even has SequentialAccess mode, which buffers on a column-by-column value for rows which contain huge values (somewhat rare/extreme). See http://www.npgsql.org/doc/performance.html for more info on Npgsql internal buffering.

Comment: The PostgreSQL paragraph you quoted pretty much says it all - functions currently have to complete before any result is sent to the client, forcing PostgreSQL to do server-side buffering of the entire resultset. This can be worked around by returning a cursor.

Comment: Thank you @Shay-Rojansky - but for me, it didn't say it all, because I can see still two scenarios left open by that. Either 1.) Executing any block of SQL over the wire to Postgres is really just like executing an anonymous function, and all the same issues apply - including, the results of any selects are fully buffered before any data is returned over the wire. Or 2.) It's a completely different situation, in which case I still want to find out, for each of `SELECT *` and `FETCH ALL`, exactly what does in fact happen, and exactly what buffers, if any, are created in this case.

Comment: Sure. The key thing to understand IMHO is that the server-side buffering behavior is a problem related to how PostgreSQL runs *functions*. You can execute the most complicated SQL outside of a function and it will stream without buffering. And returning a cursor can also bypass buffering, simply because the function terminates very early (right after setting up the cursor).

Comment: @bmju if it is possible, then Postgres doesn't use buffers on server side. The data are send to client immediately. Only when the execution requires materialization, then server side buffers (temp files) are used.

Comment: @PavelStehule - see @ LaurenzAlbe's answer (and the comments on it). Unfortunately FETCH ALL FROM huge is always generating a massive temp file. Not the answer I wanted to hear (and not fully clear why), but it seems completely true.

Comment: @MikeBeaton - It is related to plpgsql implementation of Set Returning Functions - not to `FETCH ALL` command. If you use C function without tuplestore, then server side buffers should not be used (depend on plans).

Comment: @PavelStehule I have done another test. If I execute FETCH ALL FROM cursor I get a 140MB disk buffer file reported in pg logs. If I execute FETCH 5000000 FROM cursor I see a 70MB disk buffer file. (Regardless of how many rows I actually stream.) This does seem to be a cursor issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some experimenting it seems like PostgreSQL behaves like this:

- Fetching many rows with `SELECT * FROM large` will not create a temporary file on the server side, the data are streamed as they are scanned.
- If you create a server side cursor with a function that returns `refcursor` and fetch rows from the cursor, all returned rows are collected on the server first. This leads to the creation of a temporary file if you run `FETCH ALL`.

Here are my experiments with a table that contains 1000000 rows. `work_mem` is set to 64kb (the minimum). `log_temp_files` is set to 0 so that temporary files are reported in the server log.

- First attempt:

  ```
  SELECT id FROM large;
  ```

  Result: no temporary file is created.
- Second attempt:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lump() RETURNS refcursor
     LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
  $$DECLARE
     c CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM large;
  BEGIN
     c := 'c';
     OPEN c;
     RETURN c;
  END;$$;

  BEGIN;
  SELECT lump();
   lump
  ------
   c
  (1 row)

  FETCH NEXT FROM c;
   id
  ----
    1
  (1 row)

  FETCH NEXT FROM c;
   id
  ----
    2
  (1 row)

  COMMIT;
  ```

  Result: no temporary file is created.
- Third attempt:

  ```
  BEGIN;
  SELECT lump();
   lump
  ------
   c
  (1 row)

  FETCH all FROM c;
     id
  ---------
         1
         2
         3
  ...
    999999
   1000000
  (1000000 rows)

  COMMIT;
  ```

  Result: a temporary file of about 140MB is created.

I don't really know why PostgreSQL behaves that way.

Comment: @laurenz-albe, the server-side buffering seems to be a result of `generate_series()` as opposed to the use of cursors. If you create a huge table (e.g. by doing `SELECT * INTO data FROM generate_series(1, 10000000);`) and then change your function to select from that, no temp file is generated. This shows that cursors definitely do *not* always cause server-side buffering.

Comment: Doh. Thanks for that observation. I have rewritten the answer.

Comment: Maybe your `work_mem` setting was different and the data were buffered in RAM?

Comment: @Laurenz-Albe - I've realised what is going on. You do need to look for temp files in `base\pgsql_tmp` as well, because the buffer file is only reported (in the log) when it is released, but it first appears (in the directory) at some point while the data is streaming. (Result: the temp file appears in the log just before the user sees the first row of data on anything using `libpq` (e.g. `psql`), but just after the user sees the last row of data on a streaming client program built on a streaming data access layer like `Npgsql`!)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - it's 140MB, not 14MB...!

Comment: This is confirmed as a bug/feature/design choice of PostgreSQL by Tom Lane in the PostgreSQL forums: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/17679.1487683929%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I think the key point here is that normally people don't `FETCH ALL`, and the behaviour is no problem if you just fetch one or a few rows.

Comment: It's true, but still a bit weird... because SELECT * in this context does work. Also, in general, I wouldn't have expected PostgreSQL to buffer the entire cursor resultset before returning anything (not when the underlying SELECT definitely does not buffer anything, as we can see). But hey! And thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is missing in your question is if you really need a plpgsql function as opposed to an inlined sql function.  I only bring it up because your description is a simple scenario - `select * from hugetable`.  So I am going to answer the question based on that information.

In that case, your problem is not really a problem, because the function call can be invisible.  My point is that if you can write the function as an inline SQL function, which you don't indicate one way or another, you don't need to worry about this particular limitation of plpgsql `RETURN QUERY`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS TABLE (id INT)
AS
$BODY$
SELECT * FROM bar;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Look at the plan:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT * FROM foo() LIMIT 1;

QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1
   ->  Seq Scan on bar  (cost=0.00..14425.00 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning time: 0.082 ms
 Execution time: 0.031 ms
(6 rows)
```

There is no entire result set being filled out then returned.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions

I will defer to the other answers here if you really need plpgsql to do some non-sql foo, but this really needed to be said here.

Comment: That is a very useful point @DB140141, and it could definitely help me or someone else who wants to stream large data. But actually (though I did not say so because I thought it would confuse the issue), I really want to contribute to supporting cursors correctly in a library! So the basic question *for me* was (and still is), if I DO have a cursor referencing very large data (for whatever reason, just... IF I do), then is `FETCH ALL FROM cursor` always daft, or can it sometimes make perfectly good sense?

Answer (score -1):

When you need to process an astronomically large set of data and you use `SELECT * FROM` or `RETURN QUERY` you need an astronomically large buffer not only on the server, but also on the client. And then you need to wait astronomically long for it to arrive over your network. There are no cursors used internally.

When using a `CURSOR` you can overcome the buffering but a `FETCH ALL` would just be silly because you force the cursor to give up what it was designed to do: present data from the database piecemeal. On the server side you avoid the buffering because data is sent over the network as it is generated, but the client side would still need to buffer all the data.

Some frameworks (like Hibernate) do buffering behind the scenes, but I do not know of similar functionality in lower-level libraries like Npgsql or the JDBC driver. But that buffering comes at a price too, in particular an astronomically large number of `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 23950378000` or something like that.

In either case, if you indeed have such large amounts of data to process, you are **much** better off doing the processing server-side, e.g. in a PL/pgSQL function, and then send the results to the client. Not only are server computers usually more capable than clients, you also avoid most of the network overhead.

Comment: Thank you! But I think this can't all be correct. Those client side issues depend on the server side issue I was asking about. If you are right that `FETCH ALL FROM cursorname` "[o]n the server side you avoid the buffering because data is sent over the network as it is generated" then it all depends on my client. Npgsql streams the data from Postgres to me one row at a time as well. And if I want (need) to *use* the data one row at a time, and then discard it, then if cursors work as you say *on the server*, I think there would indeed still be a sensible use case for FETCH ALL from the client.

Comment: As mentioned above, it's not true you need an "astronomically large buffer" on the client - this is going to depend on your client implementation. Npgsql does not buffer the entire resultset, but only row by row.

Comment: Shay is right. And the JDBC driver can also be configure to **not** buffer the result

Comment: Revisiting this much later - the statement that you are "much better off doing the processing server-side" (because "server computers are usually more capable than clients") also seems quite dangerous and wrong. Whereas you can have very easily add database clients, it's very hard to add servers. Doing lots of server-side processing means your only server is going to be overloaded quite quickly.

Comment: Not to mention speaking of big data Redshift Spectrum based realm, the client is the powerhorse and the "server" is just a layer in the architecture.